# Troubles using jquery on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to use Jquery in order to validate a form's input. On top of that, I want to auto-fill some fields if they are left blank.
Here is how I proceed :

```js
$(form).submit(function () {
    var result = true;
    var timeRegex = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/;
    if ($("#newStartTime").val().length == 0) $("#newStartTime").val("00:00");
    if (!timeRegex.test($("#newStartTime").val())) {
        $("#newStartTime").wrap("<div class='error' />");
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
});
```

What's happening here is that the input is set to 00:00, but the submit is rejected (and the field wrapped as an error). If I re-click on submit, it works fine.

The way I see things, Jquery doesn't treat the modifications made after the 'submit' was called.
If that's the case, is there a way to achieve what I want without using ".submit()" twice ?
If I'm mistaken, what's wrong ?

Comment: Your assumption is true Jquery doesn't treat the modifications made after the 'submit' was called.

Comment: Not the answer , but an ugly hack : You can make the submit be clicked programatically, like this : `$( "#Submit" ).click();`. Here click will happen twice, but one time via code and another time manually via your click action .

Comment: @SreekeshOkky At least I got that part right :] Would you have any hints for the second part ?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I'd prefer to avoid this, if possible

Comment: It work for me http://jsfiddle.net/JjBMR/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an event listener on the submit button click

by example :

```
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    var newValue = $('#field1_real').val(); 
    $('#field1').val(newValue);
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Comment: I'm going to stick to that solution and if I don't find a cutter way, I shall mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the blank fields, it would be best to have the server handle the default values rather than Javascript.  It could provide the defaults when the Form is sent to the browser, or apply defaults if their missing when the browser submits the Form.

It keeps the hack out of your JS, and will still work if JS is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(form).submit(function() {
. 
. 
.
});
```

Here, form means ID of the form?

If it is Id, try like this

```
$('#formId").submit(function() {
. 
. 
.
});
```

Comment: That's the case, indeed.